# Is there any way to reduce sum 100M float elements of an array in CUDA?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, thrust, reduction

I'm new to CUDA. So please bear with questions with trivial solutions, if any.

I am trying to find the sum of 100M float elements of an array. From the following code one could see that I've used a reduction kernel and  [thrust.](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) I suppose the kernel stores the sum in `g_odata[0]`. As all the elements are same in `g_idata` the result should be `n*g_idata[1]`. But you could clearly see the results are incorrect for both of them.

1. What am I getting wrong? How could I achieve my target?
2. Every reduction kernel I found is for integer datatype. e.g. the highly recommended [Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA.](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf). Is there any specific reason to that?

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <thrust/reduce.h>
    #include <thrust/execution_policy.h>


    using namespace std;


    __global__ void reduce(float *g_idata, float *g_odata) {

    __shared__ float sdata[256];


    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    sdata[threadIdx.x] = g_idata[i];

    __syncthreads();

    for (int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *=2)
    {
        int index = 2 * s * threadIdx.x;;

        if (index < blockDim.x)
        {
            sdata[index] += sdata[index + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }


    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        atomicAdd(g_odata,sdata[0]);
    }




    int main(void){

    unsigned int n=pow(10,8);
    float *g_idata, *g_odata;

    cudaMallocManaged(&g_idata, n*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&g_odata, n*sizeof(float));

    int blockSize = 32;
    int numBlocks = (n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){g_idata[i]=6.1;g_odata[i]=0;}


    reduce<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(g_idata, g_odata);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    cout << g_odata[0] << "\t" << (float)n*g_idata[1] << "\t"<< (float)n*g_idata[1]-g_odata[0]<<endl;

    g_odata[0]=thrust::reduce(thrust::device, g_idata, g_idata+n);

    cout << g_odata[0] << "\t" << (float)n*g_idata[1] << "\t"<< (float)n*g_idata[1]-g_odata[0]<<endl;



    cudaFree(g_idata);
    cudaFree(g_odata);

    }
```

Result:

```
6.0129e+08  6.1e+08 8.7097e+06
6.09986e+08 6.1e+08 13824
```

I am using CUDA 10. `nvcc --version` :

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

Details of my GPU `DeviceQuery`:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 750"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          10.0 / 10.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 1999 MBytes (2096168960 bytes)
  ( 4) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     512 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1110 MHz (1.11 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2505 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device supports Compute Preemption:            No
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 10.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 10.0, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the thrust result, you're just running into the limits of `float` resolution.  I don't think there is anything wrong with your results.  Yes, they don't match.  There are plenty of questions explaining why.  You could probably get a match if you switch from `float` to `double`.  For your own kernel, as you have written it, it expects that the array size is a multiple of the block size.  But your data array does not meet this requirement.  Therefore you are using that particular realization incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you are confused about the results here is a lack of understanding of floating point arithmetic.  [This whitepaper](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html) covers the topic pretty well.  As a simple concept to grasp, if I have numbers represented as `float` quantities, and I attempt to do this:

100000000 + 1

the result will be: 100000000  (write some code and try it yourself)

This isn't unique to GPUs, CPU code will behave the same way (try it).

So for very large reductions, we get to the point (often) where we are adding very large numbers to much much smaller numbers, and the results aren't accurate from a "pure math" point of view.

That is fundamentally the problem here.  In your CPU code, when you decide that the correct result should be 6.1*n, that kind of multiplication problem is not subject to the limits of adding large numbers to small ones that I just described, so you get an "accurate" result from that.

One of the ways to prove this or work around it, is to use `double` representation instead of `float`.  This doesn't really completely eliminate the problem, but it pushes the resolution to the point where it can do a much better job of representing the range of numbers here.

The following code primarily has that change.  You can change the `typedef` to compare the behavior between `float` and `double`.

There are a few other changes in the code.  None of them are the cause of the discrepancy you witnessed.

```
$ cat t18.cu
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <thrust/reduce.h>
    #include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

    #define BLOCK_SIZE 32
    typedef double ft;
    using namespace std;

    __device__ double my_atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
    {
      unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =
                              (unsigned long long int*)address;
      unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;

      do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed,
                        __double_as_longlong(val +
                               __longlong_as_double(assumed)));

      // Note: uses integer comparison to avoid hang in case of NaN (since NaN != NaN)
      } while (assumed != old);

      return __longlong_as_double(old);
    }
    __device__ float my_atomicAdd(float* addr, float val){
        return atomicAdd(addr, val);
    }

    __global__ void reduce(ft *g_idata, ft *g_odata, int n) {

    __shared__ ft sdata[BLOCK_SIZE];

    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    sdata[threadIdx.x] = (i < n)?g_idata[i]:0;

    __syncthreads();

    for (int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *=2)
    {
        int index = 2 * s * threadIdx.x;;

        if ((index +s) < blockDim.x)
        {
            sdata[index] += sdata[index + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }


    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        my_atomicAdd(g_odata,sdata[0]);
    }




    int main(void){

    unsigned int n=pow(10,8);

    ft *g_idata, *g_odata;

    cudaMallocManaged(&g_idata, n*sizeof(ft));
    cudaMallocManaged(&g_odata, sizeof(ft));
    cout << "n = " << n << endl;
    int blockSize = BLOCK_SIZE;
    int numBlocks = (n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    g_odata[0] = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){g_idata[i]=6.1;}


    reduce<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(g_idata, g_odata, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    cout << g_odata[0] << "\t" << (float)n*g_idata[1] << "\t"<< (float)n*g_idata[1]-g_odata[0]<<endl;

    g_odata[0]=thrust::reduce(thrust::device, g_idata, g_idata+n);

    cout << g_odata[0] << "\t" << (float)n*g_idata[1] << "\t"<< (float)n*g_idata[1]-g_odata[0]<<endl;



    cudaFree(g_idata);
    cudaFree(g_odata);

    }
$ nvcc -o t18 t18.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t18
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
n = 100000000
6.1e+08 6.1e+08 0.00527966
6.1e+08 6.1e+08 5.13792e-05
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```